# How many rows will be returned by the below query

Tags: mysql

Will this retrieve rows from 0 to 499 or 1 to 500?

If 1 to 500 then how do i get the 1st rows?

```
select email from email_data where value='A_HNI' limit 0,500;
```

Comment: it will return 0-499....

Comment: @Torrezzzz: Is there a row `0`? I think not

Comment: @AmeyaWalawalkar: Yu can just try it yourself. Or look it up in the doc. Why ask something so simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will return at maximum 500 rows, beginning with the first, because the offset of the initial row is 0. Your statement is equivalent to:

```
select email from email_data where value='A_HNI' limit 500;
```

See the documentation of the `LIMIT` clause of the [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):